# What all to modify to get the OpenIDM-OpenDJ sync working for a custom schema structure?

Tags: ldap, opendj, openidm

I am new to OpenIDM and Open DJ and trying to get the bi-directional sync working. I could run the related examples sample2b and sample2c and see the sync working.

I need to get this working for my set-up having an OpenDJ with BaseDN as dc=cas,dc=mj,dc=go. Under this base DN, I have a top level organisational unit IDUsers with dn as ou=IDUsers,dc=cas,dc=mj,dc=go. The IDUsers has a number of users of a custom object type. An example user is: uid=john.miller,ou=IDUsers,dc=cas,dc=mj,dc=go. I am able to do the CRUD on these using OpenDJ REST API and through control panel UI.

But, I am not able to get the bi-directional sync working as explained in sample2b and sample2c.

Please could anyone explain what all to change to get this working? I could not get a clear documentation on what files to change.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

before having sync working, you might want to check that you can access 
your OpenDJ object via the OpenIDM REST API with call like this:

```
$ curl
--cacert self-signed.crt
--header "X-OpenIDM-Username: openidm-admin"
--header "X-OpenIDM-Password: openidm-admin"
--request GET
"https://localhost:8443/openidm/system/ldap/account/object_id"
```

See [documentation about REST API](http://openidm.forgerock.org/doc/integrators-guide/index.html#rest-supported-read).

If that does not work, then you have to configure your connexion to OpenDJ. This is explained in the section [Configuring Connectors](http://openidm.forgerock.org/doc/integrators-guide/index.html#openicf-provisioner-conf) of the doc.